# How to upload a video file to S3 without input field?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am making a react app that can take video footage using the webcam, and then I can upload the video file into S3. Right now, I have a download button that downloads the video from the front-end and saves it locally. Then the back-end will find the video in the local system and uploads it into S3. I want to replace the download button as the upload button, so that I can upload the video straight to S3 without downloading it locally.

I have been searching on the internet about how to upload files to S3 without using the input field in the front-end, but I couldn't find any. Are there any dependencies or packages that I can use to solve this problem?

Front-end:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";

const WebcamStreamCapture = () => {

const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
const mediaRecorderRef = React.useRef(null);
const [capturing, setCapturing] = React.useState(false);
const [recordedChunks, setRecordedChunks] = React.useState([]);

const handleStartCaptureClick = React.useCallback(() => {
  setCapturing(true);
  mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(webcamRef.current.stream, {
    mimeType: "video/webm"
  });
  mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener(
    "dataavailable",
    handleDataAvailable
  );
  mediaRecorderRef.current.start();
}, [webcamRef, setCapturing, mediaRecorderRef]);

const handleDataAvailable = React.useCallback(
  ({ data }) => {
    if (data.size > 0) {
      setRecordedChunks((prev) => prev.concat(data));
    }
  },
  [setRecordedChunks]
);

const handleStopCaptureClick = React.useCallback(() => {
  mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
  setCapturing(false);
}, [mediaRecorderRef, webcamRef, setCapturing]);

const handleDownload = React.useCallback(() => {
  if (recordedChunks.length) {
    const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
      type: "video/webm"
    });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "react-webcam-stream-capture.webm";
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    setRecordedChunks([]);
  }
}, [recordedChunks]);

return (
  <>
    <Webcam  
    audio={false} ref={webcamRef} />
    {capturing ? (
      <button onClick={handleStopCaptureClick}>Stop Capture</button>
    ) : (
      <button onClick={handleStartCaptureClick}>Start Capture</button>
    )}
    {recordedChunks.length > 0 && (
      <button onClick={handleDownload}>Download</button>
    )}
  </>
);
};

   ReactDOM.render(<WebcamStreamCapture />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Back-end:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Enter copied or downloaded access ID and secret key here
const ID = '';
const SECRET = '';

// The name of the bucket that you have created
const BUCKET_NAME = '';

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: ID,
    secretAccessKey: SECRET
});

const uploadFile = (fileName) => {
    // Read content from the file
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName);

    // Setting up S3 upload parameters
    const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: 'footage.webm', // File name you want to save as in S3
        Body: fileContent
    };

    // Uploading files to the bucket
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
    });
};

uploadFile('react-webcam-stream-capture.webm'); // the file name in the parameter needs to exist inside the local machine.
```

You can run 'npm start' to run the front-end and 'node' to run the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can [generate a presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) and use that URL to upload your file in the front-end, with an HTTP request.

That way, you can:

1. Make a request to the back-end to get the presigned URL in the front-end
2. Make a PUT HTTP request in the front-end with the URL the back-end has provided, to upload your file